# Read csv file as a vector

Tags: r, csv

Hi I was trying to read a csv file, I would like to get a vector
the inside of file like

```
head filetoread.csv 
    0610010K14Rik,0610011F06Rik,1110032F04Rik,1110034G24Rik,1500011B03Rik,1700019L03Rik,1700021K19Rik, blah,blah,...
```

in R session:

```
c <- read.csv("filetoread.csv")
> c
   [1] X0610010K14Rik  X0610011F06Rik  X1110032F04Rik 
...
> str(c)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2840 variables:
 $ X0610010K14Rik : logi 
 $ X0610011F06Rik : logi 
 $ X1110032F04Rik : logi 
 $ X1110034G24Rik : logi 
...
```

but I wanna something like:

```
> c
[1] "X0610010K14Rik" "X0610011F06Rik" "X1110032F04Rik" ...
 str(c)
 chr [1:2840] "X0610010K14Rik" "X0610011F06Rik" "X1110032F04Rik"...
```

Comment: Just to explain why `read.csv` does what you're seeing, it defaults to `header=TRUE`, which means the first line (here the ONLY line) is assumed to be a header, so it makes them the names of columns, which are then never filled. You could in fact get what you're after by running `c<-names(read.csv("filetoread.csv"))` to extract a vector of the column names. Obviously @akrun's answer below is a much better way to go, just putting this here for explanation's sake.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Real help me to understand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `scan`

```
scan("filetoread.csv", sep=',', what = "", quiet = TRUE)
#[1] "0610010K14Rik" "0610011F06Rik" "1110032F04Rik" "1110034G24Rik" 
#[5] "1500011B03Rik" "1700019L03Rik" "1700021K19Rik" " blah"         "blah"
```